# Set User Password Manually

Tags: users

Can I manually set a user's password?

I know I can change it but it is asking for the current password which is null at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current password it is asking for when you change it is not the password of the user who is having their pasword changed, but the password of the admin (you) who is doing the changing.